# Jenkins Pipeline Robot framework test results not shown on main page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework

I have Robot framework tests built into a Jenkins pipeline that consists of the Building Blocks: Build, Release, Deploy, Test.

All of these can be started from a Jenkins job called Master that is generated by a Jenkinsfile.
I had hoped that the Robot framework test results would be visible on the Master job page, like they are when I run the tests as a separate freestyle job.
But instead they are buried under Buildingblocks>Test>build#

I find this an unintuitive place for our developers to go digging down into after they have started a build from Master to find the test results.

Is there a way to put the test results on the Master job page?

This is the publishing step of my pipeline:

```
            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        step(
                            [
                                $class               : 'RobotPublisher',
                                outputPath           : '',
                                outputFileName       : '**/output*.xml',
                                reportFileName       : '**/report*.html',
                                logFileName          : '**/log*.html',
                                disableArchiveOutput : true,
                                passThreshold        : 0,
                                unstableThreshold    : 0,
                                otherFiles           : "**/*screenshot*.png",
                            ]
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [HTML publisher plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/htmlpublisher/) and add that as a step in your pipeline script.
This way the log file will show up on the Master Job homepage, on the left side panel, where you have options like Status, Changes, Configure, and so on.

Here is a sample on how your step could be:

```
publishHTML([
    allowMissing: false, 
    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, 
    keepAll: true, 
    reportDir: 'dir of your log.html file', 
    reportFiles: 'log.html', 
    reportName: 'Your custom Report name', 
    reportTitles: 'Your custom Report tile'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After the stage that runs robot, add a post section (or insert into an existing post section), a script with a RobotPublisher step. I have added it to the final post-always section like this, where my output path on the robot command line is '--outputdir robot_results_for_robot_framework':

```
  post {
    always {
      script {
        step(
          [
            $class              : 'RobotPublisher',
            outputPath          : 'robot_results_for_robot_framework',
            outputFileName      : 'output.xml',
            reportFileName      : 'report.html',
            logFileName         : 'log.html',
            disableArchiveOutput: true,
            otherFiles          : "*.png,*.jpg",
          ]
        )
      }
    }
  }
```